# GNS construction of a weight

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, bilinear-form, quantum-groups

In the theory of quantum groups in the operator algebraic setting, one deals with weights (instead of positive linear functionals).

Definition: A weight is a function $\phi $ : $A^+ \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ such that

1) $\phi(a + b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$ for all $a, b \in A^+$

2) $\phi(\lambda a) = \lambda \phi(a)$ for all $a \in A^+$ and all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$

In the literature it is said that one can make a unique GNS-construction (By considering $\mathcal{N}_\phi = \{a \in A; \phi(a^*a) < \infty \}$) for any weight on a $C^*$-algebra. However, how can one define the "sesquilinear" form $(a| b) = \phi(b^*a)$ with a weight, since it is not linear?

Comment: I don't know about quantum groups, nor very much about weights, but it seems indeed that $\phi(b^*a)$ would already not be defined if $b^*a$ is not in $A^+$. Maybe, writing an arbitrary element of a C*-algebra as a sum of A+iB, with A,B self-adjoint, then $A=A_+ -A_-$ with $A_{\pm}$ positive may allow to extend $\phi$ to a linear map on the whole algebra.

Comment: you can prove that $b^*a < a^*a + b^*b$ and that $\phi(b^*a) \leq \phi(a^*a + b^*b)$. I don`t think you can decompose and arbitrary self-adjoint $a = a_+ - a_-$, both positive.

Comment: @Henrique: sure you can! This follows from the continuous functional calculus. $a_{+}$ and $a_{-}$ are $\text{max}(a, 0)$ and $\text{min}(a, 0)$ respectively.

Comment: (Or I guess $a_{-}$ is $-\text{min}(a, 0)$ if you want to subtract it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is to define $\phi $ by linearity on $$\mathcal M_\phi=\text {span}\,\{a\in A^+:\ \phi (a)<\infty\}. $$ Then the inequality from your comment shows that $b^*a\in \mathcal M_\phi $ whenever $a,b\in\mathcal N_\phi $.

Comment: So you can extend a weight to the whole of $A$ by linearity?

Comment: No. Linearity makes no sense for things like $a-b$ when $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=\infty$.